# Remove line break from Oracle Sql database column

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to remove a line break when selecting a column in an Oracle database.

So far, I have only found

```
SELECT translate(myCol, chr(10)||chr(13), ' ') from myTable
```

but that does not return results when making ' ' to ''.

How do I remove the line break and not replace it with another sign?

Comment: Try to use the replace function. Replace accepts the empty string as parameter: replace(myCol, chr(13) || chr(10), '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention on how `translate` works: it "translates" single characters, one by one and positionally; for example, this

```
select translate('abcdefg', 'ac', ' ') from dual
```

substitutes `'a'` with blank and `'c'` with nothing, because the second string has nothing in the second position, thus removing `'c'`.
So, you may need something like:

```
translate(myCol, 'X' || chr(13) || chr(10), 'X')
```

This changes `'X'` into `'X'`, `chr(13)` and `chr(10)` into nothing, so it just removes `chr(10)` and `chr(13)`

Also, notiche that in this way you don't only remove the concatenation of `chr(13)` and `chr(10)`, but every occurrence of `chr(13)` and `chr(10)`.